# How to run django from python idle?

Tags: python, django, python-idle

I know there are several softwares for Django like Pycharm,etc. But I want to know can I run a webpage created by Django from Python IDLE. Is there any way if there is please help me.

Comment: Why do you want to do it? I think there are some dirty hacks to run it from Idle but what is the profit?

Comment: You want to:
a) play around with API (then use `python manage.py shell`)
b) run web service from IDLE?

PS. PyCharm is not dedicated to Django only. Have you gone through the tutorial?

Comment: One can open webpages in a browser from python code with the `webbrowser` module.  The IDE is irrelevant for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IDLE and pycharm are *development* tools. When you run the code as webpage, you shouldn't use them.

In particular -- idle is an editor for one file at a time, while pycharm is better for project development.

Any way, you can use any text editor for editing the python files.

Comment: One can edit more than one file at a time with IDLE, but it is true that there is no notion of a connection between files.

Answer (score 0):

Django is a web framework. you can not compile it, you can just write the code and then the browser will show the page you designed.
you can use Atom or Sublimetext for this purpose.test